# Assigning error to api in try and catch transaction

Tags: api, yii2

i have the following code (assume transaction is working properly)

```
try{
 if (!$model->save() {
       $return = Yii::t('app/job', 'JOB_NOT_FOUND');
       trow new \Exception();
     }
   } catch(Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
        return (new ApiResponse)->error(null, ApiResponse::EXPECTATION_FAILED, $return);
}
```

i receiver php error undefined variable return

Any effort is highly appreciated

Comment: not the problem, but incorrect anyway: trow => throw

Comment: the `$return` is out of scope for the catch block, that is why you are getting this error,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` is a [PHP keyword and could lead to confusion](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Are you using PHP 5.x? PHP keywords are allowed since PHP 7.0.0

Try this:

```
try{
    if (!$model->save() {
        throw new \Exception(Yii::t('app/job', 'JOB_NOT_FOUND'));
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollBack();
    return (new ApiResponse)->error(null, ApiResponse::EXPECTATION_FAILED, $e->getMessage());
}
```